Proplem with Strapi client v4
I am watching a video in youtube tutorial working with strapi here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPFbxwRGhiQ&list=PLVpp0SvtYtdfMvoSB1NwHq3J0MFHSz5FQ&index=17
at 4:34 ,You can see the field relationthe relation .I did exactly and save then the client crash the report.
then i go to the file Profile (\my-project\src\api\profile\content-types\profile )
It add this
"user": {
"type": "relation",
"relation": "oneToOne",
"target": "plugin::users-permissions.user",
"inversedBy": "profile"
}
same with the User-permission (\my-project\src\extensions\users-permissions\content-types\user)
"profile": {
"type": "relation",
"relation": "oneToOne",
"target": "api::profile.profile",
"mappedBy": "user"
}
I can't get it what wrong and how to fix (the strapi of video use is v3 and i use v4)
Can any body help me ,thank you very much

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Strapi v4 is not compatible with V3, u messed model by copying this to schema.json
